# Can I rename every combobox with same name in excel?

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

There are a lot of combobox in sheet and they are appending dynamic. But all of combobox' assignments are same. They will run a function in macro. Can I rename all of combobox with same name? Or how can I do what I want?

```
Sub ekranadi()
  Dim mainworkBook As Workbook
  Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook
  For i = 1 To mainworkBook.Sheets.Count
    If Left(mainworkBook.Sheets(i).Name, 5) = "Ekran"
     Then ComboBoxEkranAdı.AddItem mainworkBook.Sheets(i).Name
    End If
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Use forms controls, not activeX and assign them all the same macro

Comment: I tried this. But I writing for example 'ComboBox1.AddItem' in macro and I have combobox1,combobox2,...

Comment: my macro is`Sub ekranadi()                         
Dim mainworkBook As Workbook
Set mainworkBook = ActiveWorkbook
For i = 1 To mainworkBook.Sheets.Count
    If Left(mainworkBook.Sheets(i).Name, 5) = "Ekran" Then
        ComboBoxEkranAdı.AddItem mainworkBook.Sheets(i).Name
    End If
Next i
End Sub`

Comment: Edit your post and include your code there. It is very difficult to read it in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding of your requirement is correct, the macro below will show you how to achieve the effect you seek.

A user form has a collection named `Controls` that contains every control on the form.  Instead of `MyControl.Name` you can write `Controls(6).Name` if 6 is the index number within `Controls` of `MyControl`.

The macro below outputs the index number, type name and name of every control on a form.  If the control is a ComboBox, it adds three items to it with each item value being unique to the box.

**Edit**

Sorry I did not read your question carefully enough.  I do not use controls on worksheets because I consider controls on user forms to be more powerful and more convenient.  Controls on worksheets are further complicated by having two types: those loaded from the Controls toolbox and those loaded from the Forms toolbox.  Functionality depends on which type you have.

To test the new macro `DemoWorksheet`, I loaded worksheet "Test" with both types of control.  The macro shows how to fill both type of combo box via their collections.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DemoUserForm()

  Dim InxCtrl As Long

  Load UserForm1

  With UserForm1

    For InxCtrl = 0 To .Controls.Count - 1
      Debug.Print Right(" " & InxCtrl, 2) & " " & _
                  Left(TypeName(.Controls(InxCtrl)) & Space(10), 15) & _
                  .Controls(InxCtrl).Name
      If TypeName(.Controls(InxCtrl)) = "ComboBox" Then
        With .Controls(InxCtrl)
          .AddItem InxCtrl & " A"
          .AddItem InxCtrl & " B"
          .AddItem InxCtrl & " C"
        End With

      End If

    Next

  End With

  UserForm1.Show

End Sub
Sub DemoWorksheet()

  Dim Inx As Long

  With Worksheets("Test")

    Debug.Print "Shapes.Count=" & .Shapes.Count
    Debug.Print "OLEObjects.Count=" & .OLEObjects.Count

   For Inx = 1 To .Shapes.Count
     With .Shapes(Inx)
       Debug.Print "S " & Right(" " & Inx, 2) & " ShapeType=" & _
                   ShapeTypeName(.Type) & " Name=" & .Name
       If .Type = msoFormControl Then
         Debug.Print "     FormControlType=" & FormControlTypeName(.FormControlType)
         If .FormControlType = xlDropDown Then
           .ControlFormat.AddItem "S " & Inx & " A"
           .ControlFormat.AddItem "S " & Inx & " B"
           .ControlFormat.AddItem "S " & Inx & " C"
           .ControlFormat.DropDownLines = 3
         End If
       End If
     End With
   Next
   For Inx = 1 To .OLEObjects.Count
     With .OLEObjects(Inx)
       Debug.Print "O " & Right(" " & Inx, 2) & " OleType=" & _
                   OLETypeName(.OLEType) & " Name=" & .Name
       If Left(.Name, 8) = "ComboBox" Then
         .Object.AddItem "O " & Inx & " A"
         .Object.AddItem "O " & Inx & " B"
         .Object.AddItem "O " & Inx & " C"
       End If
     End With
   Next

  End With
End Sub
Function FormControlTypeName(ByVal FCType As Long) As String

  Dim Inx As Long
  Dim TypeName() As Variant
  Dim TypeNumber() As Variant

  TypeName = Array("ButtonControl", "CheckBox", "DropDown", "EditBox", "GroupBox", _
                   "Label", "ListBox", "OptionButton", "ScrollBar", "Spinner")
  TypeNumber = Array(xlButtonControl, xlCheckBox, xlDropDown, xlEditBox, xlGroupBox, _
                     xlLabel, xlListBox, xlOptionButton, xlScrollBar, xlSpinner)

  For Inx = 0 To UBound(TypeNumber)
    If FCType = TypeNumber(Inx) Then
      FormControlTypeName = TypeName(Inx)
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next

  FormControlTypeName = "Unknown"

End Function
Function OLETypeName(ByVal OType As Long) As String

  If OType = xlOLELink Then
    OLETypeName = "Link"
  ElseIf OType = xlOLEEmbed Then
    OLETypeName = "Embed"
  ElseIf OType = xlOLEControl Then
    OLETypeName = "Control"
  Else
    OLETypeName = "Unknown"
  End If

End Function
Function ShapeTypeName(ByVal SType As Long) As String

  Dim Inx As Long
  Dim TypeName() As Variant
  Dim TypeNumber() As Variant

  TypeName = Array("AutoShape", "Callout", "Canvas", "Chart", "Comment", "Diagram", _
                   "EmbeddedOLEObject", "FormControl", "Freeform", "Group", "Line", _
                   "LinkedOLEObject", "LinkedPicture", "Media", "OLEControlObject", _
                   "Picture", "Placeholder", "ScriptAnchor", "ShapeTypeMixed", _
                   "Table", "TextBox", "TextEffect")
  TypeNumber = Array(msoAutoShape, msoCallout, msoCanvas, msoChart, msoComment, msoDiagram, _
                   msoEmbeddedOLEObject, msoFormControl, msoFreeform, msoGroup, msoLine, _
                   msoLinkedOLEObject, msoLinkedPicture, msoMedia, msoOLEControlObject, _
                   msoPicture, msoPlaceholder, msoScriptAnchor, msoShapeTypeMixed, _
                   msoTable, msoTextBox, msoTextEffect)


  For Inx = 0 To UBound(TypeNumber)
    If SType = TypeNumber(Inx) Then
      ShapeTypeName = TypeName(Inx)
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next

  ShapeTypeName = "Unknown"

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you your answer but I dont want to use userform. Can I solve this without userform?

Comment: I have added a new section to my answer which I hope will show you how to achieve the effect you seek.

Comment: Oww it's perfect answer. Thank you very much ! Have a good life :)