# Copy text from textbox and paste into cell of new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I searching a way to copy all the text of the *TextBox* that is created by a previous macro and paste it into Cell A1 on *Sheet3*.

Any suggestions??

Here is the previous macro:

```
  Sub Copy()
    Dim srng As Range
    Dim sWs As Worksheet: Set sWs = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set srng = sWs.Range("L1", sWs.Range("L" & sWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    With Sheets("Sheet4").Shapes("Textbox 2").OLEFormat.Object
        .Text = Join(Application.Transpose(srng), vbCrLf)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the created `TextBox` stays in the worksheet? Like if you run it 10 times you'll end up having 10 `TextBoxes`?

Comment: What happens the first time the macro is run and there isn't any `TextBox`?

Comment: The Textbox will be the same, in this case Textbox1, and will be always the same on the Sheet3.

Comment: Do you have some code already that you could share? It would help to see how you are creating these text boxes.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28773446/973283) was to a question about ComboBoxes but I believe it will give the information you need to find the latest TextBox.

Answer (score 0):

You can count the shapes. Then place the text in the top counted textbox.
For example.

```
    Sub Copy()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim Rws As Long, Rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim shP As Shape

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet4")

    With sh
        Rws = .Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, "F"), .Cells(Rws, "F"))
    End With

    With ws.Shapes
        i = .Count
    End With

    Set shP = ws.Shapes(i)

    shP.TextFrame.Characters.Text = Join(Application.Transpose(Rng), vbCrLf)

End Sub
```